# Unable to run example code with VTK 8.2.0, CMAKE 3.14.6, Visual studio 2015 x64, Windows10

Tags: cmake, vtk

I am trying to get started with VTK and downloaded the latest source code 8.2.0.
Followed below links to compile a sample example.

[Building VTK Windows](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows)

[VTK Set Up in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvbhyDh8r0)

[Install VTK with visual studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vobxbVy_iV8)

[Compile VTK 8.2.0 with Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 10](https://zhangresearch.org/post/compile-vtk-8.2.0/)

I have successfully installed the VTK at specified location without any error but when I try to build a sample example, everytime I run `CMAKE`, i get below error
`Skipping SimplePointsReader`

CMAKE windows shows below message

```
Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Skipping SimplePointsReader: 
Configuring done
```

Afterwords when I generate the example solution and build the solution, it does not generate any `exe`. The path in environment variable is updated correctly to the folder where `VTK` is installed.

My system info is as below:

```
VTK Source 8.2.0 
CMAKE 3.14.6 
Visual studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Windows10 Enterprise x64
Not configuring with QT
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that CMake can't find on its own your installation of VTK. I'll assume that you are trying to compile this [example](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/IO/SimplePointsReader/).

You can manually tell CMake where VTK is by setting the var `VTK_DIR` in CMake GUI. You will have to specify the folder that contains the file `VTKConfig.cmake`.

It is located under `${your_vtk_install}/lib/cmake/vtk-${vtk_version}/` :

[image: vtk localisation in cmake]

If it works CMake should tell you something like `VTK_VERSION: ${vtk_version}`.

Comment: I have the same problem on ubuntu. When running make, nothing happens. Specifiying the directory where vtk-config.cmake is located, whether in the cmake file or via the command line didn't help